# WooCommerce Crud Product Variant omitting second variant

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am importing products from a clients API into WooCommerce using PHP. I would like to make use of the WooCommerce CRUD to ensure all product information gets set correctly.
I have a static function in a class within my plugin that creates the WooCommerce product.

Within the loop the product is supposed to create two attributes, one for color and one for size. But within my WordPress backend I can see that only one product attribute is being created?

This is what I am seeing in my backend in WordPress:
[image: WooCommerce backend]

This is what is in the database:
[image: Database Sample]

Why would WooCommerce not create the second Product Variant?

```php
/**
 * Create a product using a ImportProductModel
 *
 * @param importProductModel $productModel The product to create
 *
 * @return int|WP_Error The product ID on success, or WP_Error on failure.
 * @throws WC_Data_Exception
 */
public static function createWooCommerceProduct(importProductModel $productModel): WP_Error|int {
    $WCProduct = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $WCProduct->set_name($productModel->getProductName());
    $WCProduct->set_sku($productModel->getCode());

    $allProductAttributes = [];

    $allColors = $productModel->getAllColors();
    $allSizes = $productModel->getAllSizes();

    if(!empty($allColors)){
        $elementCount = count($allProductAttributes); // Is also ID & Position
        $colorAttribute = self::createWooCommerceProductAttribute($elementCount, 'Colour', explode("|", $allColors));
        $allProductAttributes[] = $colorAttribute;
    }

    if(!empty($allSizes)){
        $elementCount = count($allProductAttributes); // Is also ID & Position
        $sizeAttribute = self::createWooCommerceProductAttribute($elementCount, 'Size', explode("|", $allSizes));
        $allProductAttributes[] = $sizeAttribute;
    }

    $WCProduct->set_attributes($allProductAttributes);
    $WCProductId = $WCProduct->save();

    update_post_meta($WCProductId, 'importProductModelId', $productModel->getProductId());

    return $WCProductId;
}

/**
 * Create a Attribute for a WooCommerce Product
 * @param int $id The ID of the attribute
 * @param int $position The position of the attribute
 * @param string $name The name of the attribute
 * @param array $values The values of the attribute
 * @return WC_Product_Attribute The created attribute
 */
private static function createWooCommerceProductAttribute(int $id, string $name, array $values): WC_Product_Attribute {
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    $attribute->set_name($name);
    $attribute->set_id($id);
    $attribute->set_options($values);
    $attribute->set_visible(true);
    $attribute->set_variation(true);

    return $attribute;
}
```

Comment: $elementCount dont use it to define ID. Allow woo to do it on its own $colorAttribute = self::createWooCommerceProductAttribute('Colour', explode("|", $allColors)); Also i would add after sku $WCProduct->set_type('variable');  to make sure its variable.

Comment: @Snuffy won't the `$WCProduct_set_type` be implied from the new `WC_Product_Variable()` though? I have subsequently removed the ID but my issue still persists